# PBE-SHA1-3DES uses 168 bit triple DES?

Tags: encryption, openssl

I'm using the following command to encrypt my private key file using OpenSSL:

```
$ openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform DER -in private_key.pem -out private_key.der  -v1 PBE-SHA1-3DES
```

The documentation states that the option `-v1 PBE-SHA1-3DES` will encrypt using triple DES, but doesn't mention which keying option it is using. Can I assume that it uses 168 bit triple DES?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer seems to be yes, when I read the file from Java(see also my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894131/exception-when-decrypting-a-der-file-generated-with-openssl-input-length-must)), I can get the algorithm viz.:

`1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.3 from algParams.getAlgorithm()`

Googling this yields: [pbeWithSHAAnd3-KeyTripleDES-CBC](http://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/submissions/1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.3.html)

See also: http://www.oid-info.com/get/1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.3

This is a 3key triple DES, which entails 168 bits.

```
public static byte[] decryptPrivateKey(byte[] key) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    PBEKeySpec passKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec("p".toCharArray());

    EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo encryptedKey = new EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(key);
    System.out.println(encryptedKey.getAlgName());
    System.out.println("key length: " + key.length);
    AlgorithmParameters algParams = encryptedKey.getAlgParameters();
    System.out.println(algParams.getAlgorithm());
```